# Measuring the time between 2 inputs with tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, experimental-design

I have a game where 2 players think they are competing to get the fastest reaction times, but it is rigged so that the winner is random each round. I am trying to put a function in here to override the random win if one player is super slow (so they don't know that it is rigged). I have tried all sorts of solutions and my biggest challenge so far has been getting tkinter to accept multiple inputs. I ended up splitting the function into 3 to avoid having my program crash but now I am getting new errors that I don't understand.

`

```
def record_game(e):
    global KEY1, KEY2, game_data, game_round, win_num

    if e.keysym not in (KEY1, KEY2):
        return
    elif e.keysym == KEY1:
        unbind_all()
        begin = t.time()
        root.after(0, timer_1)
    elif e.keysym == KEY2:
        unbind_all()
        begin = t.time()
        root.after(0, timer_2)
    else:
        win_num = random.randint(1, 2)
        unbind_all()
        root.after(200, ask_blast)


def timer_1(e):
    global KEY1, KEY2, game_data, game_round, win_num

    if e.keysym not in (KEY1, KEY2):
        return
    elif e.keysym == KEY2:
        end = t.time()
        elapsed = end - begin
        if elapsed > ELAPSED_TIME:
            win_num = 1
            print(elapsed)
        else:
            win_num = random.randint(1, 2)
            unbind_all()
            root.after(200, ask_blast)
    else:
        win_num = random.randint(1, 2)
        unbind_all()
        root.after(200, ask_blast)


def timer_2(e):
    global KEY1, KEY2, game_data, game_round, win_num

    if e.keysym not in (KEY1, KEY2):
        return
    elif e.keysym == KEY1:
        end = t.time()
        elapsed = end - begin
        if elapsed > ELAPSED_TIME:
            win_num = 2
            print(elapsed)
        else:
            win_num = random.randint(1, 2)
            unbind_all()
            root.after(200, ask_blast)
    else:
        win_num = random.randint(1, 2)
        unbind_all()
        root.after(200, ask_blast)
```

`

I am expecting this to check if the differnece between key stokes was more than ELAPSED_TIME. If it is greater, a specific player should win; if it is lesser, a winner should be selected at random. It should then move onto ask_blast.

Instead I get:
`

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1921, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/tkinter/__init__.py", line 839, in callit
    func(*args)
TypeError: timer_1() missing 1 required positional argument: 'e'

Process finished with exit code 0
```

`

It seens like the first 2 errors have somthing to do with Tkinter not wanting to wait for multiple inputs but I am not sure... Any help would be very much appreciated :)

(appologies in advance if I've missed somthing obvious. Please note that I have a grand total of ~28hrs of python experience over the past month or so)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. You should provide minimal example that we can run. So that we can see errors

Comment: Try running the code without this line: `root.after(0, timer_1)`

Comment: That stopped the error crash! But now it does not continue to the next step (def timer_1 or 2). Is there another way to do that without root.after()?

Comment: Sorry, dumb question above. When I call the next function (timer_1 or timer_2), that is when I get flooded with error messages which tells me there is something wrong with those functions... I cannot figure out what those errors mean.

Comment: `TypeError: func_name() missing 1 required positional argument: 'arg_name'`. This error basically means that you are using a function somewhere in the code without passing anything to it. timer_1 instead of timer_1(e), timer_2 instead of timer_2(e)

Comment: Perhaps this option will help: `root.after(0, lambda: timer_1(e))`. You'd better provide a minimal example that we can copy and run.